# Python Lists Matrix Concatenation

Tags: python-3.x, matrix-multiplication

Having 2 lists, can be different or same lengths.

```
a = [('1','1','2'), ('2','2','2','2'), ('3','3')]
b = [('7','8','8','9'), ('0','0','4','5')]
```

How can I add / concat the lists such that I'll get the following output.

Also, not sure if I'm using the right terminology here. Appreciate any corrections.

```
c = [
('1','1','2','7','8','8','9'),('1','1','2','0','0','4','5'),
('2','2','2','2','7','8','8','9'),('2','2','2','2','0','0','4','5'),
('3','3','7','8','8','9'),('3','3','0','0','4','5')
]
```

Essentially, `c = [ (a[0] + b[0]), (a[0] + b[1]), (a[1] + b[0]), (a[1] + b[1]).....`

Thus far, I've just been using for loops. I've looked at itertools.product, but the output isn't right. Additionally, if I increase it to 3 lists, then the combination becomes larger.

Comment: Use smaller data values (easier to read without loss of info).  What you tried so far?  Matrix concat is just double loop.

Comment: Try this out `[(x+y) for x in a for y in b]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track, thinking to use `product`.

```py
from itertools import product

a = [('1','1','2','3','4','5','6'), ('2','2','2','2','2','2','2'), ('3','3','2','1','1','1','1')]
b = [('7','8','8','9'), ('0','0','4','5')]

paired_up = product(a, b)
c = [sum(tuples, start=()) for tuples in x]  # The default start is 0, which leads to TypeErrors.

print(c)
# [('1', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '8', '9'),
#  ('1', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '0', '0', '4', '5'),
#  ('2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '7', '8', '8', '9'),
#  ('2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '0', '0', '4', '5'),
#  ('3', '3', '2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '7', '8', '8', '9'),
#  ('3', '3', '2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '4', '5')]
```

### More than two lists? Pass them all to `product`.

```py
d = [('0',), ('1',)]  # Let's add another list to the mix.
paired_up = product(a, b, d)  # It gets passed to `product` with the rest.
c = [sum(tuples, start=()) for tuples in paired_up]
print(c)
# [('1', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '8', '9', '0'),
#  ('1', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '8', '9', '1'),
#  ('1', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '0', '0', '4', '5', '0'),
#  ('1', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '0', '0', '4', '5', '1'),
#  ('2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '7', '8', '8', '9', '0'),
#  ('2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '7', '8', '8', '9', '1'),
#  ('2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '0', '0', '4', '5', '0'),
#  ('2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '0', '0', '4', '5', '1'),
#  ('3', '3', '2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '7', '8', '8', '9', '0'),
#  ('3', '3', '2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '7', '8', '8', '9', '1'),
#  ('3', '3', '2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '4', '5', '0'),
#  ('3', '3', '2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '4', '5', '1')]
```

Comment: If there were 3 lists, would I just do triplets = product(paired_up, c)
d = list(map(sum_tuples, triplets))

Comment: It would be even better to do `product(a, b, c)`.

Comment: oh, ok. I didn't know I can do that. I'll have to go read up. Thank you

Comment: Added an example of this.

Comment: Thanks! Can I also assume this is a generator? If I have very large lists, I'm a little worried about memory issues.

Comment: It's straightforward to [convert the list comprehension to a generator expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehensions)—turn the brackets into parentheses. In that case, yes.

Comment: If I have 3 lists, 15k x 40k x 12k, might you happen to know a way I can efficiently and quickly filter them? Currently I've used your above solution but converted `c` into a generator and am running filter() against it.

Answer (score 1):

toRex already provided you the answer as I was typing this.

```
a = [('1','1','2','3','4','5','6'),
     ('2','2','2','2','2','2','2'),
     ('3','3','2','1','1','1','1')]
b = [('7','8','8','9'),
     ('0','0','4','5')]

print ([(i+j) for i in a for j in b])
```

The output will be:

```
[('1', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '8', '9'), 
 ('1', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '0', '0', '4', '5'), 
 ('2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '7', '8', '8', '9'), 
 ('2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '0', '0', '4', '5'), 
 ('3', '3', '2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '7', '8', '8', '9'), 
 ('3', '3', '2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '4', '5')]
```

Input:

```
a = [('1','1','2','3','4','5','6'),
     ('2','2','2','2','2','2','2'),
     ('3','3','2','1','1','1','1','5','5','5'),
     ('1','2','3')]

b = [('7','8','8','9'),
     ('0','0','4','5'),
     ('1','2')]
```

Output:

```
[('1', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '8', '9'), 
 ('1', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '0', '0', '4', '5'), 
 ('1', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '1', '2'), 
 ('2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '7', '8', '8', '9'), 
 ('2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '0', '0', '4', '5'), 
 ('2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '1', '2'), 
 ('3', '3', '2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '5', '5', '5', '7', '8', '8', '9'),
 ('3', '3', '2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '5', '5', '5', '0', '0', '4', '5'),
 ('3', '3', '2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '5', '5', '5', '1', '2'), 
 ('1', '2', '3', '7', '8', '8', '9'), 
 ('1', '2', '3', '0', '0', '4', '5'), 
 ('1', '2', '3', '1', '2')]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. May I ask, if I have 3 or more lists, might there be a better way to handle it?

Comment: My solution handles the case of multiple lists.

Comment: just saw it and reading now to understand. Thank you for your answer @AryaMcCarthy

Comment: I just tested with more items. It works. Let me add a few more examples

Comment: @JoeFerndz by '3 or more lists', the asker meant more than just `a` and `b`, not that the size of `a` and `b` change. (See the asker's comment on my question.)